# Installing SSMS in Windows Core

Tags: powershell, installation, cmd.exe, ssms, unattended

I'm trying to: `start "" /w ".\smss-setup-enu19.exe" /passive ssmsinstallroot="c:\program files\ssms"` but encountering this error:↓ (syntaxes using `"` around path and etc are checked!)

**Powershell**:

[image: PS-Err]

**CMD**:

[image: CMD-Err]

***CMD Result***: (Opens a black square then immediately disappears, `taskmgr` checked, the task ended!)

[image: CMD-Result]

[MS Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms-19?view=sql-server-ver16)

---

1. I Have VM in VMware workstation with Windows Server 2022 core, 2GB RAM.
2. And another one with Ubuntu 22.04, installed SQL server 2022.(in docker)

Needs install SSMS in (1) and work with 2's Databases.

**Installation logs:**

[log1](http://viuna.ddns.net/SSMS-Setup-ENU_20220727151356.log) &
[log2](http://viuna.ddns.net/SSMS-Setup-ENU_20220728014718.log)

Comment: Have you tried to use the full path: `start "" /w "Z:\RawPrograms\MS-Windows\Programming\Database\smss-setup-enu19.exe" /passive ssmsinstallroot="c:\program files\ssms"`?

Comment: Yeah i'm pretty sure a GUI tool like SSMS isnt going to work in server core. Install it on server desktop or a normal windows to remotely manage the sql instance installed on the server  core.

Comment: `Start-Process` needs an actual file path as the first parameter, not "". You might be better off using call like: `& ".\ssms-setup-enu19.exe" /Install /Quiet /Norestart FOO="bar" ...`. I also recommend adding `/Logs log.txt`, then checking the log file to see what the installer failed on

Comment: @Cpt.Whale, Please take a look the Ref↑

Comment: @mgae2m I meant in powershell (Ref commands are only CMD). The CMD command is fine syntax-wise, so you may want to just enable logging and see why it doesn't install.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale tried what you wrote, not installed.

Comment: Seems my pictures immediately broke! That was right.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have a windows server core (2012 R2) VM to test this on. Running this **cmd** command worked fine. I got a pop-up window with an installation progress bar for each component until it was completely installed:

```
start "" /w c:\temp\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe /Passive SSMSInstallRoot=c:\test\SSMS
```

My SSMS was installed to `c:\test\SSMS\`. To start it, I ran the exe:

```
c:\test\SSMS\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe
```

---

Be aware that all kinds of stuff does **not** work in server core (no GUI).  Later versions of windows server like 2016/2022 are more stripped-down, so they may not be able to display the various windows until rebooted, if at all

SSMS installation errors and such all get written to a log file in your `%TEMP%` folder automatically. Look at it if your installation doesn't succeed:

```
notepad C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\SsmsSetup\SSMS-Setup-ENU_20220727124801.log
```

If you continue to have issues, try running the .exe directly to attempt to display the install wizard, which might show errors etc:

```
C:\Users\> C:\temp\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe
```

or try running in quiet mode to hide the UI altogether if it can only display black boxes:

```
start "" /w c:\temp\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe /Quiet SSMSInstallRoot="c:\program files\SSMS"
```

Comment: `C:\temp>start "" /w c:\temp\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe /Quiet SSMSInstallRoot="c:\Program Files\SSMS"` not work!
The log file: `http://viuna.ddns.net/SSMS-Setup-ENU_20220727151356.log`

→running the .exe directly, Opens dark square!

Would you remote me with anydesk?

Comment: I reinstalled windows server, using your mentioned codes, no success returned this log: (http://viuna.ddns.net/SSMS-Setup-ENU_20220728014718.log ).  Try `C:\Users\> C:\temp\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe`, appears black square and end task, not succeed. Indeed `SSMS` not installed and the answer not worked for me!

Comment: Your answer is not eligible bounty worth! you copied same the ref (below the question) advise that not work for me. This is not work for me. I tried `start "" /w ".\smss-setup-enu19.exe" /passive ssmsinstallroot="c:\program files\ssms"` and ask question because the problem!

Comment: As I sent two log files in case `start "" /w "Z:\RawPrograms\MS-Windows\Programming\Database\smss-setup-enu19.exe" /passive ssmsinstallroot="c:\program files\ssms"` and `start "" /w c:\temp\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe /Quiet SSMSInstallRoot="c:\program files\SSMS"` not working, what is the problem?

Comment: You wrote: `start "" /w c:\temp\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe /Quiet SSMSInstallRoot="c:\program files\SSMS"` but SSMS is 32bit program! You want earn false answer?!

Comment: @mgae2m `"c:\program files\ssms"` is the location you provided in your question. You can install the software wherever you'd like, or just exclude `SSMSInstallRoot` altogether if you want it to use the default location

Comment: I cannot test on server 2022 and I cannot read your log files, but if you're getting black squares, then you may want to install the compatibility pack first: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/server-core-app-compatibility-feature-on-demand